# Why can not inherit from Interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

In Java, why can not I inherit from Interfaces?

If the case is that the interfaces do no provide the implementation of the methods, then how are we able to inherit from Abstract Classes.

Comment: Your premise is wrong.  You *can* inherit from an interface.  You just can't currently inherit *implementations* from interfaces, but that has everything to do with the fact that interfaces have no implementations for you to inherit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot inherit from interfaces, because **interfaces provide only abstraction, not functionality**.

Notes from the comments below (thanks to @Mark Peters and @qqilihq) :

- [Interfaces can inherit from interfaces](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Extendinganinterfacewithinheritance.htm)
- Both abstract classes and interfaces are forms of inheritance, but currently only abstract classes support code inheritance. Interfaces provide type inheritance. In Java 8, interfaces will provide code inheritance as well.

You can also check the [Official Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), it's a good starting point for Java knowledge.

Comment: Wait for Java 8.  I would say both are forms of inheritance, but currently only abstract classes support implementation inheritance.  Interfaces provide type inheritance.  In Java 8, interfaces will provide code inheritance as well.

Comment: [addition] Interfaces *can* inherit from interfaces.

Comment: Also good to note that you can inherit as many interfaces as you want but only a single abstract class

Answer (score 3):

This is because abstract classes and interfaces are inherently different types of objects. Abstract classes define functionality while inheritances act as a framework.

EDIT: As I posted above you can inherit as many interfaces as you want but only a single abstract class

Answer (score 0):

Java supports only single inheritance via the `EXTENDS` keyword. The idea is that you can "inherit" from multiple interfaces in the same class.

Therefor the `IMPLEMENTS` keyword is used to "inherit" an interface.

A class that `IMPLEMENTS` an interface gains access to all declarations in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact you **can** inherit from interfaces - but only to extend their interface.

You can create `abstract` classes that do some or all of the work required by an interface.

You can then `extend` your `abstract` classes to make real classes. Even overriding functionality from the abstract class if you wish.

```
// close
interface Closeable {
  public void close();

}

// open and close
interface Openable extends Closeable {
  public void open();

}

// Simplistic implementation
abstract class AbstractCloseable implements Closeable {

  @Override
  public void close() {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "-close");
  }

}

// Simplistic implementation
abstract class AbstractOpenable extends AbstractCloseable implements Openable {
  boolean open = false;

  @Override
  public void open() {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "-open");
    open = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    super.close();
    open = false;
  }

}

class PortHole extends AbstractOpenable implements Openable {

  public void clean() {
    if (!open) {
      System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "-clean");
    } else {
      System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "-fall out");

    }
  }

}

public void test() {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  PortHole p = new PortHole();
  p.open();
  p.clean();
  p.close();
  p.clean();
}
```

Prints:

```
PortHole-open
PortHole-fall out
PortHole-close
PortHole-clean
```